# How to sort database according to Order By clause Using ASC and DESC simultaneously with where condition

Tags: android, sqlite

How to sort database according to Order By clause where previous date comes down(DESC) and from current date should come top as ASC.
I have taken system current date in a variable after that how to check with where condition,please let me know.

for previous date it should follow DESC and from current Date it should follow ASC.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. I'm not at all sure the straightforward `ORDER BY previousdate DESC, currentdate ASC` is what you're after.

Comment: cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.DGADATATABLE, columns, "equipid = '"+equipid+"' and dateadded BETWEEN '"+start+"' AND '"+end+"'"  , null, null,null, "dateadded DESC");

Comment: for previous date it should follow DESC and from current Date it should follow ASC

Answer (score 0):

You could use separate queries and combine them with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM contacts
      WHERE systemdate > date
      ORDER BY date DESC, priority DESC, time ASC)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM contacts
      WHERE systemdate <= date
      ORDER BY date ASC, priority DESC, time ASC)
```

Comment: systemdate is not a database variable,so its not taking.

Comment: That's what you wrote in your own queries. How to get the current date (in a format that can be used to compare it with the values in your database) is a different question.

Comment: yes,i just wanna know is it possible to take non-database variable for where condition.

Comment: To ask a question, do not use a comment but the "Ask Question" button.